# difference between width auto and width 100% for floated elements

Tags: html, css

As specified in the answer of [difference between width auto and width 100 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent) the width auto takes full width but in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5bQP/) the width auto doesn't take the full width but when we apply 100% to this then only it takes full width. How the width auto takes its element actually?

Demo summary

html

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul{background-color: gray;}
li{background-color: red; float: left; clear: left; width: auto;}
```

Comment: You have answered this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent/17468803#17468803

Comment: 100% = width of parent ::;
auto = depending on other params (display|float) may be as parent or as less as its possible

Comment: Yeah! I've answered the question but asking here the width auto when we float the elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/p5bQP/1/

CSS

```
ul{
  background-color: gray; 
  float:left;
  }
li{
  background-color: red; 
  float: left; 
  clear: left; 
  width:100%;
  }
```

Comment: I'm asking the width auto vs percentage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist the floating on the `li` element.

If you remove the floating part from your css like that:

```
ul{background-color: gray;}
li{background-color: red; width: auto;}
```

then it works fine.

Comment: I know that but why floating element doesn't take its full width by assigning auto but takes 100%.

Comment: Floating elements was handled like an inline-element. [http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm]

Comment: If so width 100% also should take as width auto.