# CSS set div container to fit body width not window width

Tags: html, css

Hi I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color: red;">

    <div style="margin: 0px auto; width: 960px;">

        Text here...

    </div>

</div>
```

The wrapper-div doesn't fit the `<body>`, when I resize the browser window to be lower than 960px, the wrapper gets as small as the browser window size. I want to get the wrapper at least as wide as the content inside it. I really have a hard time figuring this one out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are inside element size known already? Like something mentioned by you as 960px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set wrappers style to: `min-width: 960px` .. same as inner div

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of upper div

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color: red; width: 960px;">

    <div style="margin: 0px auto;">

        Text here...

    </div>

</div>
```

for a detailed description refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent)