# After adding div, value goes in new row

Tags: html, css, row

After I added div that defining backgound color of text, whole value of 'Ime' goes to new row. Why?
Something like this:
Ime:
Stephen

This is code:

```
   <div class="rightmiddle">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
<div class="divmobilni">
<div class="floatright"><img src="images/nokia-lumia-720.jpg" height="66px" width="50px" /></div>
Ime:<div class="imepozadina"> <?php echo $row['Ime'];?></div>
Okrug: <?php echo $row['Okrug'];?>
<br />
Telefon: <?php echo $row['Telefon'];?>
</div>
<br />
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
imepozadina{
background-color:red;
width:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `<div>` is displayed as a block element as default, which takes 100% of width without further styling.

You might add `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` in order to shrink the div to its content width.

Please refer [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) for more information on `display` in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you set width property to auto the browser will automatically calculate,and occupy all the available space. It is the default for div and P. to understand the difference between setting a div 100% width and auto look at this answer [[difference between width auto and width 100 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent])