# Is .small-12 meaningless?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I don't see any differences when I include `small-12` or not.

How is `class="medium-6 columns"` different than `class="small-12 medium-6 columns"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In foundation, and most grid systems, the column width definition (12, 6, 3) generates a `width: XX%` style property for the element.

Therefore, `.small-12` adds `width: 100%` within the small viewport you've defined in your settings file. While this may not have a visual change (since by default the width: auto of the div will make it appear 100%, that is the purpose of the class. I suppose if you threw other classes onto a column that added left/right padding/margin etc it could be an issue. Give it a try!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent) may clarify the difference between width: auto and width: 100%, and the reason it may be a good idea to add '.small-12', and thus add this width property to this element.