# Cannot get div to widen to include all floated elements

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've converted a bootstrap date module to use only Angular(still in the middle of the conversion). [Here is the demo page with the behavior I want to fix.](https://raymondcheung.github.io/angular-daterangepicker/demo.html)

Click on the input field under "Your Date Range Picker" to see the daterangepicker.  I've attached a screenshot of what you should see:

[image: This is what it looks like now, the three elements should be side-by-side, instead of on top of each other like they are here.]

The issue I'm having is that the wrapper(div.daterangepickerdropdown-menu.opensright.ltr.show-calendar) is set to width:auto, but the three child elements, ranges, left calendar, and right calendar are set to float:left.  For some reason they end up wrapping so that they stack vertically, and I can't figure out why they aren't side by side horizontally.  I've tried playing with clears, setting overflow:hidden to the wrapper, and nothing seems to work.  I've spent 4+ hours with the chrome debugger playing with css rules and can't get the wrapper to widen as much as necessary to put all three child elements horizontally.

For a comparison of what it should look like [this](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested your dropdown menu within a div with class `col-md-4`, which has a defined width.

The working demo has placed the dropdown menu outside of this column.

Even though you are positioning it absolutely it is still inheriting the max-width of the column. (you can see this by setting the dropdown menu width to 50%)

You can solve this by changing your HTML structure and positioning your dropdown menu in a similar way to the demo, or by overriding the width using a fixed setting which will adequately fit the child elements, e.g. `width: 170%`.

Comment: I thought since I am setting `width:auto` on the dropdown menu, that would override what it is inheriting.  Do you know what that is not the case?

Comment: You are correct in that width:auto will expand the menu to fit the elements inside - but it can only expand to occupy the same width as its containing block, in this case col-md-4. More here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent

Comment: Thank you so much.  I added a wrapper div around the dropdown menu and set that to position relative, so the dropdown menu would stop inheriting anything outside of the daterange-picker element(to prevent interaction between my module and anything outside of it).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the following container:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 demo"></div>
```

You should remove `position-relative` from the above element so that your date-picker does not inherit properties from it.

Alternatively, you can apply `position: relative` to the `<div class="row"></div>` element just above the `.demo` element and align your date-picker accordingly.

Comment: This answer is also correct in addition to the one I marked.

Comment: @user594044 Thanks