# Why is the size of a nested row with multiple columns inside col-auto more than content width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

If I understand it correctly, the `col-auto` classes in Bootstrap is supposed to only use the natural width of the content. When I use `col-lg-auto` in the code below, the width becomes larger than the content.

I've created this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/andbjer/pen/QZymBB) that demonstrates the issue.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Replace col-lg-auto with col-lg and add class flex-grow-0 -->
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the `row` inside `col-lg-auto` only has one column child, then it works as expected. I'm also able to achieve the layout I want if i replace the class `col-lg-auto` with the classes `col-lg` and `flex-grow-0`.

Can someone please explain why the width of `col-lg-auto` does become larger than the content width in this scenario? Can i not use a row with multiple columns inside a column that has the class `col-auto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a "bug". The columns inside the `col-lg-auto` are full width `col-lg-12` so they're filling 100% width as expected. If you want the inner columns to have consume min width, use `flex-lg-column` (`flex-direction:column`) on the inner row...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">Col</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Replace col-lg-auto with col-lg and add class flex-grow-0 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-auto">
            <div class="row flex-lg-column">
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-lg-12 bg-blue">Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/l5kv3hu9Av

Note: For IE 11 you'll need to add:

```
/* IE 11 helper */
.flex-lg-column > .col-lg-12 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic way to research those questions is to go to bootstrap.css and check definitions:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css#L82-L92

```
.col-lg-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css#L652-L657

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-auto {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      width: auto;
      max-width: none;
    }
}
```

That means in "lg-mode" it has width `auto` which is not related to the content width - [difference between width auto and width 100 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent)

Comment: you say it is not related to the content width, but the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content) says "Use `col-{breakpoint}-auto` classes to size columns based on the natural width of their content."

Comment: I try to say you: do not hesitate to go to sources.