# How do I increase the size of a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

This is my first project using Django.
I am creating a form as follows and as you can see on the screenshot below, the form is just too narrow. I'd like the input fields to go across the whole screen which is not possible when the form is that narrow. How can I increase the width of the form?

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Row, Field
from ..models import EvilSnippet

class AddSnippet(forms.Form):

class Meta:
    model = EvilSnippet

code_language = forms.ChoiceField(
    label = "Select Language",
    choices = (("Java", "Java"), ("Python", "Python"), ("C#", "C#")),
    required = True,
)

severity = forms.ChoiceField(
    label = "Severity",
    choices = (("HIGH", "HIGH"), ("MEDIUM", "MEDIUM"), ("LOW", "LOW")),
    required = True,
)

description = forms.CharField(
    label = "Description",
    required = False,
    #widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'})
)

code = forms.CharField(
    label = "Code",
    required = False,
    widget=forms.Textarea()
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AddSnippet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_id = 'id-addSnippet'
    self.helper.form_class = 'uniForms'
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_action = 'submit_snippet'

    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Row(
            Field('code_language', wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
        ),
        Row(
            Field('severity', wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
        ),
        Row(
            Field('description', wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
        ),
        Row(
            Field('code', wrapper_class='col-md-6'),
        )
    )

    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

and

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<!-- <form action = '' method="post"> -->
<!-- Very Important csrf Token -->
 {% csrf_token %}
 <!-- <table> -->
     {% crispy form %}
 <!-- </table> -->
<!-- </form> -->
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: For this you'll need some CSS styling. Look into the width property. Something like `form#id-addSnippet { width: 100%;}`

Comment: That's it - thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! I posted my comment as an answer, feel free to mark it as accepted. You might also consider adding the `css` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the display of a webpage, you need to use CSS. For you case, you'll want to use the width property. Something like this should work for you:

```css
form#id-addSnippet {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will set the width of the form with id `id-addSnippet` to 100% of its containing block.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468803/9638991) for more details about what `width: 100%` means.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be your `wrapper_class` for your input elements? You have the boot strap class `col-md-6` which takes half of the available space maybe try `col-md-12`???