# in flexbox how to have children width equal to parent width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I have difficulties understanding how the width property works on children items of a flex container ?

I would like to know what is the reliable cross-browser way of having the child element having a width that takes all the available width of the parent (different from `width:100%;` as stated in this question : [difference between width auto and width 100 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent))

---

**WARNING: my question is dependent on the browser, I'm working on firefox (my version is 120.0)**

---

from [the doc](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#propdef-width), the default value of width is auto, and the other values are :

> <length-percentage [0,∞]> | min-content | max-content | fit-content(<length-percentage [0,∞]>)

I want to have a child element take the width of the parent

1. ### width auto with block works as i expect

   parent -> `display: block;`

   child -> `width: auto;`

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   | | block                                                    | |
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
2. ### width auto with flex doesn't do what i want

   parent -> `display: flex;`

   child -> `width: auto;`

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   | --------                                                     |
   | | flex |                                                     |
   | --------                                                     |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
3. ### width moz-available in flex works with firefox

   parent -> `display: flex;`

   child -> `width: -moz-available;`

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   | | -moz-available                                           | |
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

### see example :

```css
div { border: 1px solid blue; margin-bottom: 10px; }
p   { border: 1px solid red; }
.block { display: block; }
.flex  { display: flex; }

#child_1 { width: auto; }
#child_2 { width: auto;}
#child_3 {
  width: -moz-available;
  // what I found on internet :
  // width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Chrome */
  // width: fill-available;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p id="child_1">block</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p id="child_2">flex</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <p id="child_3">-moz-available</p>
</div>
```

(for non firefox users, what i see is something like that :)

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------------------------------ |
| | block                                                    | |
| ------------------------------------------------------------ |
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
| --------                                                     |
| | flex |                                                     |
| --------                                                     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------------------------------ |
| | -moz-available                                           | |
| ------------------------------------------------------------ |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**questions :**

1. how can i have the same behavior than `-moz-available`, but cross-browser compatible ?
2. will `-moz-available` behaves similarly as `width:auto;` do width parents `display:block;` ? or is there 'side effects' like `width: 100%;` that seems to act the same on simple examples, but actually do not (again : [difference between width auto and width 100 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent))
3. why `fill-available`/`-moz-available` is not even in the doc ?
4. finally, `-moz-available` has a usefull behavior in firefox : it also works when parents are block, si I can consistently use it instead of `auto` to have this desired behavior. Do you know if alternatives for other browser have the same advantage ?

Comment: Maybe you want `flex-grow`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=fill-available

Comment: @Willow indeed it works, but unfortunately not if the parent is not flex (block or grid for example)

Comment: @hugogogo , I'm not sure, but I don't think that's going to be possible. Not sure how helpful this is, but in my experience flexbox is kind of a different paradigm. When you're in a flex parent, you need to use flex tools. I recommend https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`flex: 1`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex-1-mean) will take up all available space which seems to be your requirement and represents the alternative to `width` in a flex container.

```css
.child {
  height:50px;
  flex:1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background:pink;
}

.parent {
  margin:1em auto;
  display:flex;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding:.25em;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: indeed it works and I suppose it's cross browser compatible (I cannot test that), but unfortunately not if the parent is not flex (block or grid for example)

Comment: Grid works by setting column widths to `1fr`.. like so: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZEwoVPZ

Comment: yes I know, I meant that I cannot use the same rule for whatever parents, in the purpose to create a functional css rule that I can use as classes in any situation. But actually I can, since the flex or 1fr will simply be ignored if the parent is not of the according display, so it's cool :)